# C++.net Single line of code breaks intellisense?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c++-cli, intellisense

I've been a c++.net developer for four years, and have run into several strange idiosynchrocies.  However, the most frustrating one is when intellisense, just stops working.

I have the following function:

```
Void panelXYReport::ProcessResult()
{
   try
   {
      this->panelReportBase::ProcessResult();      
      this->RequestGetSelectedTestpoints(this, selectedTestpointNumbers); //<- THIS LINE
      for each(rptTestpoint^ thisTestpoint in this->TestpointCollectedValues)
      ...
```

Intellisence works fine on the first - third line of the function.  Once I hit the event there, intellisense just stops working until the end of the function.  What I mean by stops working, is that if the cursor is beofre that line, its fine.  Afterwards, it doesn't. Here is the declaration and event information:

```
   public: 
   /// <summary>
   /// event to ask the testpoint grid which testpoints are selected
   /// </summary>
   event TestpointListEventDelegate<long>^      RequestGetSelectedTestpoints;
```

Any thoughts? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't a thirdparty addon for visual studio which improves intellisence maybe solve this, such as Visual Assist X?

> Visual Assist X improves on default
>   IntelliSense with Enhanced Listboxes,
>   parameter information that is frequent
>   and helpful, and hovering tooltips for
>   virtually all symbols. Instantly view
>   the context and definition of a symbol
>   just by clicking on it. Hover over
>   symbols while browsing code to see
>   overrides, other members of its class,
>   related enums, etc. Get the
>   information you need without hunting
>   for it.

Or maybe just upgrading to a newer version of Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm using VS2k8.  Our product is moving to 2k10 in the fall.  I may try to install visual assist X in the meantime though.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 does not have Intellisense for C++/CLI. At all. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/27/rebuilding-intellisense.aspx

Comment: @kate: well, no edition sold by MS does.  But VA-X works great with 2010 and provides it.

Comment: @Ben I know. But @greggorob64 and @Alex both appear to expect better Intellisense for C++/CLI in Visual 2010 than in VS 2008 - and will be disappointed in that expectation.

Comment: Since he never stated which VS he was using the statement that I'd expect better intellisens in VS2010 is just a false assumption. I just figured that he was using an old version of Visual Studio and therefore answered his question with the question that he might be able to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: @Kate: Agreed.  I just didn't want your emphasis "At all." to be construed to mean there is no workaround.